# How to use Activity method in another class

Tags: java, android

**This constructor doesn't work for me, ie:when i create a MainActivity object in the other class via this constructor, its throwing a null pointer exception**

```
private static MainActivity instance;
public  MainActivity getInstance()
    {
     return  instance;   
    }
```

Comment: Hi Harinarayanan, Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add a Minimal code and problem statement indicating where you want to call this and why you need it?

Comment: you have not initialized instance variable.
Please specify where you want to use this method

Comment: I want to initialize Mainactivity object in the onPostExecute method of my  AsyncTask class.I can do the same if i define my AsyncTask class as the subclass of my MainActivity, but i was experimenting if it's possible if i define AsyncTask class a seperate class.

Comment: Do you want instance or context?

Comment: `when i create a MainActivity object in the other class` never do that. You should never create an instance of Activty

Answer (score 0):

Your instance is not initialized when you call getInstance so it's default value is null.
To avoid NPE, you have to give a value to your instance, you can for example call the constructor of MainActivity
I think you are trying the Singleton Pattern, do you can check the code below

```
private static MainActivity instance = new MainActivity();
public  MainActivity getInstance(){

     return  instance;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyActivity : ExternalListener {
   val externalClass = ExternalClass(this)
   override fun printResults() {
      println("printing details from Activity: ".plus(this.javaClass.name))
   }
}

interface ExternalListener {
   fun printResults()
}

class ExternalClass(val listener: ExternalListener) {
   fun printResults() {
      listener.printResults()
   }
}
```

So your MyActivity implements an interface ExternalListener which you pass as an argument to your ExternalClass, in which you use MyActivity. printDetails() method.